# My webrequests keeps returning the wrong response why?

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

So I am trying to connect to http://cmyip.org because the content contains information about the proxy you are connecting with. Which is perfect because I am learning about making web-requests with proxies so it will show me if I actually connected with the proxy or not.

However instead of getting the content of the website I am making a request to I am getting the content of the proxy html

```
Before start thread
<html><head><title>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Subscription Edition 4.7.2.01 build2
1094</title></head><body>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Subscription Edition 4.7.2.01
build21094</body></html>
Working.
```

Why is it showing the contents of the proxy and not cmyip.org? I'm sure I am just too close to the code to see it but could really use some help.
If you try to connect to 192.99.46.182:1935 on your web browser you will see the same thing.

```
public static bool TestProxy(string proxyIP, int proxyPort)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.cmyip.org/");
            WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(proxyIP, proxyPort);
            myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            request.Proxy = myproxy;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
            request.Timeout = 2000;

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string Content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    console.WriteLine(Content);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private static void SimpleTest()
        {
            var aBool = TestProxy("192.99.46.182", 1935);
            if (aBool == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Working.");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think that Wowza Streaming Engine is an HTTP proxy?

Comment: Because as far as I know HttpWebRequest only supports http / https

Comment: So this proxy "192.99.46.182:1935" returns the weird thing<br>
While this proxy works flawlessly.. Whats the difference between them? "45.55.27.246:8080"

Comment: The difference between them is that one's a proxy, and the other isn't.